# Incorrect sheet music notes in MuseScore playback

Tags: piano, sheet-music, musescore

I'm a beginner in the piano and I'm really struggling to read sheet music. I guess I've taken up a song that's way over my head *(Kiss the Rain - Yiruma)*

I'm unable to understand why the following 2 notes are exactly the same in sheet music

[image]

As far as I know, in the F minor scale (Treble clef), the first note should have been A♭ and the 2nd should have been G but according to software Musescore, used to write the piece, both the notes are G!

You can check out my [comment](https://musescore.com/user/27057308/scores/4838600#comment-4999257) and listen to the audio of the sheet music I've marked in the comment to verify or even look at the [musescore file itself](https://ufile.io/k58vr)

I have a feeling its some issue with Musescore itself. But any guesses would be very helpful.

Comment: Try to make the question title more specific, to have the right people look into the question. I agree with your assumptions, there is still a semitone between *g* and *a flat* but have no idea, what *Musescore says* means.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I made an incorrect assumption that most of you have use the software Musescore previously so you will be able to understand, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this isn't some kind of prank ;).

Musescore's playback system is fine, the note is actually a G. However, the note symbol itself is offset by -0.5sp up and to the left, as visible in the inspector when you select the note, in the accord section. Thus it appears in the place you would expect an A♭.

The Accord offset is normally used to make notes more readable when they would otherwise be clustered too tightly in an accord. However, usually you'd not move it so much that the pitch is compromised.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was definitely not a prank. In fact even after your answer, it took me a while to figure out what you meant cause I'm such a newbie. I couldn't find anything known as `accord offset` online, but the inspector cleared out things.
I understand that a horizontal offset might be useful to make things legible, but isn't the vertical offset extremely misleading?  I can't think of a single example where it would be useful

Comment: Possibly above the staff to give it a bit more space, while maybe also moving the ledger line(s). A smaller offset could also help legibility without the risk of mixing it up with another note. .5sp is somewhat excessive there.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an error with MuseScore's playback system. I'm not too familiar with their setup, so I can't guess why this has happened, but it's a definite error.

Having checked out [the original](https://youtu.be/srdXkw0_ovY?t=28s), it's clearly be A♭–G, not a repeated G. The music written there in the score is correct, so as long as you play that and not what the MuseScore *playback* does, you'll be fine!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that there was a vertical offset in the first note due to which it seemed like the 2nd note as @sascha Rambeaud's answer mentions. I guess its a feature of the software and its very misleading. I understand that a horizontal offset on a note can make it more legible, but I don't know why anyone would ever want to use a vertical offset anywhere